# Where to get a PCR COVID test in Florence, Italy?

Tags: covid-19, italy, qatar

I am traveling to Florence in September, and then directly after that I am flying to another country (Qatar) that requires a PCR covid test performed within the last 48 hours. Does anyone know the easiest way to get a PCR covid test in Florence? Would drugstores do them, and if so, would they provide test results in English?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you need a **PCR** test and not a **rapid** (*antigen*) test?
You can have a **rapid** test in many pharmacys/drugstores in the territory for about 15€, but consider a phone call for be sure the pharmacy does the test (many do, but not all...). Also consider booking the test for avoid queue (even if nowadays it's no more a problem) and for be sure they do it at the time you need it (sometimes they do the tests only in the morning for example). Usually it's possibile ask for the english printed result, but again it's not for 100% of the drugstores, so call and ask.
If you need a **PCR** test it's not simple as above, you need a more professional structure (and consider that normally it takes 24/48 for the results). With a quick search i found [this one](https://www.lifebrain.it/en/covid-test-italy/) that has the webpage also in english, there is a phone number for info and also the option to book online (i suggest a call for be sure about the info in the webpage considering your situation). Also [this one](https://www.synlab.it/test-covid-19.html) is quite a big name in italy, they do a lot of analisys, but no english, you can still try to call and ask - in the webpage they mention the option for a 24h result and english printed result. [Third result](https://www.istitutofanfani.it/laboratorio-analisi/tampone-covid-19/), still no english, but also here they mention a fast response for travellers.
This three results are just the first names i found with a quick serach, i have not tryed any of them.